# Run Windows 11 under Linux on an iMac 2012

Tags: windows, imac, unix, virtualbox

I am booting in Linux on an iMac 27" from 2012. I wanted to install Windows 11 in VirtualBox, but that does not work.

I gave it 2 CPU's, 8 GB mem and 80 GB hdd space.
In VirtualBox I get the install screen, and when I want to start installation  I get

> System Requirements Not Met.

2 CPU's, 8 GB mem and 80 GB hdd space should be enough I guess? Any idea?

Comment: The is UEFI booting, Secure Boot and TPM as possible reasons of not meeting requirements.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: Good question. Just apt-get install from the most recent Ubuntu.... 6.1.38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it myself: just follow this super great tutorial, and you'll be done in 2 hours:

[Ubuntu LXD tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd)

Windows 11 runs great on my iMac 2012 under Linux and LXD, also with the TPM (Trusted Platform Module) instructions.

Two notes:

1. I raised the HDD space to 80 GB instead of the suggested 50 in the manual.
2. At install time I got many questions, I answered the default value everywhere.